# Running Tensor flow from R using rPython

Tags: python, r, rpython

I'm trying to use the Tensor flow Python module in RStudio using the package rPython. I am able to use the tensor flow module directly from Python.
I have a Python file called "run.py" which imports tensor flow, and I can successfully call it in the command line using "python run.py". However, when I use the rPython package and run the following

```
> python.load("python/run.py")
Error in python.exec(code, get.exception) : No module named tensorflow
```

Using the following code produces the same error

```
python.exec("
        import sys
        sys.argv = ['']
        import tensorflow as tf
        ")
Error in python.exec("\n            import sys\n            sys.argv = ['']\n            import tensorflow as tf\n            ") : 
No module named tensorflow
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Comment: A quick search for `r tensorflow` turned up [this as the first hit](https://gist.github.com/rasmusab/a8de31f8d6b09d20fcc4). It doesn't offer explanation, but suggests you need to import `sys` and set `sys.argv` first.

Comment: @Gregor I've tried that but it didn't work.